# How to use image map in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, imagemap, odoo-14

I am trying to use [image map](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp) in Odoo 14 CE.

This is my attempt to do a proof-of-concept, which is not working (mapping does not happen in the image, and the `<img>` in the client-side page does not contain `usermap="#workmap"` attribute).

```
<field name="image_parts" widget="image" usemap="#workmap"/>
<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm"/>
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Coffee" href="coffee.htm"/>
</map>
```

I am trying to make a feature that display image from field `image_parts` (customized) and it enables users to hover and see information in a small dialog popup. Moreover, the area can also be clicked to do some other methods further on.

Is there any possible solution for this or some parts of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this kind of changes, you will have to review the Map View / Map Rendered / Map Controller and Map Model JS classes.

You can find them here `/enterprise/web_map/static/src/js/`.

It's always tricky wanting to do this kind of big changes in Odoo standard views ^^

You'll need some Owl knowledge, in case you don't know you can find documentation/references/trainings/notes [on the Odoo Owl github](https://github.com/odoo/owl).

Courage